# No "exports" main defined in Node module's package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I just installed the [`zx`](https://github.com/google/zx) NPM package.

I installed it locally and imported it:

```
import { $ } from 'zx'

(async () => {
    await $`mkdir test`
})()
```

But I'm getting this error:

> No "exports" main defined in
> /home/alex/node/check-image-size/node_modules/zx/package.json

Note: I'm using Node 16.14.

What does this kind of error mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The error generally means that the library isn't setup to be used with ES modules, and is either written for CommonJS modules only, or maybe even something else. It can sometimes be fixed using Babel and/or rollup or Webpack or something, but the how is usually fiddly and rather library specific.

Comment: Can you give a [mre]? I don't get that error when running the code you show in Node 16.14.2, given the file is `index.js` package is `"type": "module"` (and without that it would be a syntax error, or the file could be named `index.mjs`).

Comment: Right, I deleted my comment @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the "main" field in your package.json ?

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#main